# .addRole and .removeRole are not functions - Discord Bot Mute Case

Tags: bots, discord, discord.js

I have scanned through all the related topics on Stack Overflow and Tried everything, but the codes just won't work :)
So I'm following a YouTube tutorial on how to mute members using a bot on Discord, and here is the error:

```
TypeError: person.removeRole is not a function
at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\index.js:39:14)
    at Client.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:436:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:801:20)
```

Here is my code, other parts are eliminated if it's necessary I can put them here.

```
case "mute":
      let person = m.mentions.members.first() || m.guild.members.fetch(args[1]); //m.guild.member(
      //console.log(person);
      if (!person) return m.reply("I don't know who this is, bro.");

      let mainrole = m.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Main");
      let muterole = m.guild.roles.cache.find((role) => role.name === "Mute");

      if (!muterole) return m.reply("Sorry they simply don't exsit.");

      let time = args[2];
      console.log(time);
      if (!time) return m.reply("That's not a time. How did you even do it?");

      person.removeRole(mainrole.id);
      person.addRole(muterole.id);
      // person.remove("Main");
      // person.add("Mute");

      m.channel.send(
        `@${person.user.tag} has now been mute for ${ms(ms(time))}`
      );

      setTimeout(() => {
        person.addRole(mainRole.id);
        person.removeRole(muterole.id); //switching the order and see how that looks like
        m.channel.send(`@${person.user.tag} has been unmuted, good job!`);
      }, ms(time));
```

Makes me wonder if the import of ms module or discord.js has some problems?
Send help please!
Thank you!

Comment: Wendy, you admitted @Syntle fixed your issue, it's customary to accept his answer. So others know this question is no longer open.(Click the Grey checkmark on his answer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since discord.js v12 you now need to use [`roles.add()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=add) and [`roles.remove()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberRoleManager?scrollTo=remove) instead of `.addRole()` and `.removeRole()`.

Comment: and if I want to remove all roles from a user, person.roles.remove(person.roles) do not work, error invalid type, do you have any idea of how this is happening

Comment: ```
TypeError [INVALID_TYPE]: Supplied roles is not an Array or Collection of Roles or Snowflakes.
    at GuildMemberRoleManager.remove (C:\Users\hp\Documents\discordBot\Codes\node_modules\discord.js\src\managers\GuildMemberRoleManager.js:127:15)
```
.etc

Comment: is it because person.roles is no an array of roles? if this is the case, how do I change it :(

Comment: Oh that's because you need to access them using `cache` so do `person.roles.cache` instead

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH